# Less file import function, what does ~ sign mean outside of quotemarks

Tags: css, less

I am using a template less file for my project and I've realized that it uses a import function like this:

```
@import ~"@{preset-fonts-file}";
```

That gave me a warning in Visual studio code like: 'uri or string expected'

So, I've thought that ~ sign should be inside of quotation marks, and changed it as:

```
@import "~@{preset-fonts-file}";
```

which is acceptable syntax for css. But that gives error and cant find the file.

Can anybody explain what is the difference and how it works? Thanks

Comment: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import

Comment: Thanks @iamentafaz, but i am using less, not sass